# Stop executing other functions after using await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion, promise

I have some issues using recursive with "async" and "await". In the code below I created a function "wait" returning a promise which I call in another function "Partition" to add some delay in a loop. After, I call this function inside "QuickSort" to implement some recursion. The first call of the "partition" function inside performed as expected. After this the value is passed inside of the callback "then" to start performing the function "quicksort", but after performing the first "await" inside this recursion the code pass to the second recursion of the second "quickSort" function inside the callback "then" without finishing the first previous recursion.

I guess this behavior is expected because I'm using the "async" "asynchronous" in the partition function, so this allows the other code to be executed.

```
 * delay in some functions. This works wll
 * in loops with the use of 'async' and 'await'
 * @param {int} ms - The time to delay;
 */
function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}
```

```
/**
 * This function perform the partition in an
 * array to perform the Quick Sort
 * @param {int} array - The numbers to be sorted
 * @param {int} low - The low index of the array
 * @param {int} high - The high index of the array
 */
async function partition(array, low, high) {
  /* This pivot is place at the rigth position */
  var pivot = array[high];
  var index = low - 1;
  /* Get all the columns child nodes */
  var columnNodes = document.getElementById("flex-box").childNodes;
  var parentElement = document.getElementById("flex-box");
  /* Change the color of the Pivot */
  var pivotColumnNode = columnNodes[high];
  pivotColumnNode.style.backgroundColor = "pink";

  for (let i = low; i < high; i++) {

    // /* Reset the color of the previous Index nodes */
    // if (columnNodes[i - 1] !== undefined) {
    //   columnNodes[i - 1].style.backgroundColor = "blueviolet";
    // }
    /* Change color of value being compare to Pivot node */
    var iNode = columnNodes[i];
    // iNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    if (array[i] < pivot) {
      index += 1;
      //Replace the values
      var valueofIndexElement = array[index];
      array[index] = array[i];
      array[i] = valueofIndexElement;

      /* Chnage the color of the node index to be chnanged */
      var nodeIndexElement = columnNodes[index];
      iNode.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      nodeIndexElement.style.backgroundColor = "brown";

      var nodeIndexElementClone = nodeIndexElement.cloneNode(true);
      var nodeIElementClone = iNode.cloneNode(true);

      parentElement.replaceChild(nodeIElementClone, columnNodes[index]);
      parentElement.replaceChild(nodeIndexElementClone, columnNodes[i]);
      //await wait(1000);
      nodeIElementClone.style.backgroundColor = "blueviolet";
      nodeIndexElementClone.style.backgroundColor = "blueviolet";
    }
    console.log("New Array: ", array);
    console.log("*********************************");
  }
  var valueOfLastGreaterElement = array[index + 1];
  array[index + 1] = pivot;
  array[high] = valueOfLastGreaterElement;

  /* Chnage the last node elements */
  var pivotColumnNodeClone = pivotColumnNode.cloneNode(true);
  var greaterColumnNodeClone = columnNodes[index + 1].cloneNode(true);

  parentElement.replaceChild(pivotColumnNodeClone, columnNodes[index + 1]);
  parentElement.replaceChild(greaterColumnNodeClone, columnNodes[high]);
  /* Reset the color of the Pivot node */
  pivotColumnNodeClone.style.backgroundColor = "blueviolet";
  greaterColumnNodeClone.style.backgroundColor = "blueviolet";

  console.log("Last: ", array);
  return index + 1;
}
```

```
/**
 * This sorts the array with the help of the partition
 * function. This uses recursion to divide an conquer the
 * array.
 * @param {int} array - The numbers to be sorted.
 * @param {*} low - The first index of the array '0'
 * @param {*} high - The length of the array.
 */
function quickSort(array, low, high) {
  debugger;
  if (low < high) {
    debugger;
    partition(array, low, high).then(value => {
      debugger;
      alert(value);
      quickSort(array, low, value - 1); // Before the partition index
      quickSort(array, value + 1, high); // After the partition index
    });
    debugger;
    // partition(array, low, high).then(value => {
    //   debugger;
    //   alert(value);
    //   quickSort(array, value + 1, high); // After the partition index
    // });
  }
}
```

The thing that I want to accomplish is how to use await in the partition function, and use this function in a recursive way on the "QuickSort" function.

Comment: You cannot take an asynchronous value and return it from a synchronous function in Javascript.  Cannot be done.  I'm struggling to see why your `partition()` function is `async` at all.  It looks like it should just be a normal synchronous function and there should be NO use of promises anywhere in this code.  Why are you even bring up asynchronous operations in this code?  And, then you can never design your quicksort algorith like you have with asynchronous operations in it.  If it has asynchronous operations in it, then it needs an asynchronous return value or callback.

Comment: Sorry to say, overall this design is just messed up.  You're trying to inject an asynchronous operation (that doesn't even seem to need to be asynchronous) into a synchronous code flow.  Cannot do that.  Either get rid of the unnecessary asynchronous operation and make everything synchronous or you need a total rethink about how to write asynchronous code and a different interface than `quicksort()` has.

Comment: I can't tell if this is a pure tech question or if you have a real problem to solve.  If you have a real problem to solve, then back up several steps, skip the implementation issues you ran into and describe what the overall problem you're trying to solve here is.  Perhaps, the actual problem is sorting some DOM elements?  And, why is asynchronous involved here at all?

Comment: If this is a pure tech question, then you can't stop the whole Javascript interpreter with `async` and `await`.  `await` will pause the execution internal to one function and when it does that, it immediately return a promise and then rest of the code after that function call continues to run (presumably to register an interest in that promise and do other things).  So, you don't just stop the entire interpreter waiting for a promise to resolve.  It does not work that way.  An `async` function is still non-blocking.  It just returns a promise when it hits the first `await` inside the function.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00 for your comments. I'm just making the code again without using promises, so all the methods will be synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your `quicksort` function does some asynchronous things as well now that it is calling an `async partition` function. But in the code

```
quickSort(array, low, value - 1); // Before the partition index
quickSort(array, value + 1, high); // After the partition index
```

the second calls doesn't wait for the first one to finish, so they will run the two partitionings concurrently. You need to chain them - using either explicit promise chaining

```
function quickSort(array, low, high) {
  if (low < high) {
    return partition(array, low, high).then(value => {
      alert(value);
      return quickSort(array, low, value - 1).then(() => { // Before the partition index
        return quickSort(array, value + 1, high); // After the partition index
      });
    });
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

or using `async`/`await` syntax:

```
async function quickSort(array, low, high) {
  if (low < high) {
    const value = await partition(array, low, high)
    alert(value);
    await quickSort(array, low, value - 1); // Before the partition index
    await quickSort(array, value + 1, high); // After the partition index
  }
}
```

Comment: Except there isn't actually anything asynchronous in the `partition()` function and therefore in the `quicksort()` function.  This looks like a misguided user of the `async` keyword to me.  Unfortunately, the OP seems to have disappeared so I've had no luck engaging them on that topic.

Comment: @jfriend00 There's a commented-out `//await wait(1000);` in the `partition` function

Comment: With no explanation for what/why that was there.  It seems quite likely that's also a misguided attempt to solve some un-described problem.  If there's a real reason for `partition()` to be async, your  answer is fine - it's just not clear to me that this is an actual asynchronous problem.  Plus, if you pause for a second on each call to `partition()`, it could take a pretty long time to sort something with the screen jumping around until it finally stops.  This is way too much of an XY-problem.  No description of the actual core problem to be solved here.

Comment: @jfriend00 Given all the DOM manipulation occuring in the `partition` function, it occured to me that it's doing some animation of a sorting algorithm. Indeed, if it's not that, then it's probably a misguided attempt at doing something else.

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi. In fact, using the await in the recursive functions works. I implemented this as my current solution. But, I was thinking to make all the method synchronous, so the code would be more accurate. Thanks,

Comment: @osvaldocarrillo Sure, you can also make everything synchronous, but then of course you cannot call `wait(1000)` any more.

Comment: @osvaldocarrillo, "synchronous" does not equate to "accurate". The two concepts are unrelated .